# Histogram Equalization image processing by c++ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

i need to make Histogram Equalization on image 
i made a Histogram and i calculate count of each pixel
but i don't know how to make Histogram Equalization
can any one help
i'm using opencv 
thnx

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, I found it. It is

```
cvEqualizeHist(src,dest);
```